# Remove duplicate values by taking latest data load

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm working with enterprise data that looks like this.

```
| load_number | id        | time     | slot_time | region | network |
|-------------|-----------|----------|-----------|--------|---------|
| 1692        | 641131146 | 00:20:00 | 00:20:00  | FX-4   | SBOB    |
| 1692        | 641131146 | 00:20:00 | 00:20:30  | FX-4   | SBOB    |
| 1442        | 570732257 | 00:20:00 | 00:20:00  | FX-4   | SBOB    |
| 1442        | 570732257 | 00:20:00 | 00:20:30  | FX-4   | SBOB    |
| 1692        | 641131147 | 00:55:00 | 00:55:00  | FX-4   | SBOB    |
| 1692        | 641131147 | 00:55:00 | 00:55:30  | FX-4   | SBOB    |
| 1442        | 570732258 | 00:55:00 | 00:55:00  | FX-4   | SBOB    |
| 1442        | 570732258 | 00:55:00 | 00:55:30  | FX-4   | SBOB    |
```

The issue is that the company has bad data practices and changes/reuses IDs, but only updates the `load_number` field.

How do I construct my sql query to pull the latest loaded data like so:

```
| load_number | id        | time     | slot_time | region | network |
|-------------|-----------|----------|-----------|--------|---------|
| 1692        | 641131146 | 00:20:00 | 00:20:00  | FX-4   | SBOB    |
| 1692        | 641131146 | 00:20:00 | 00:20:30  | FX-4   | SBOB    |
| 1692        | 641131147 | 00:55:00 | 00:55:00  | FX-4   | SBOB    |
| 1692        | 641131147 | 00:55:00 | 00:55:30  | FX-4   | SBOB    |
```

Basically every field will match except the `id` and the `load_number`. So given that every field matches except those two fields, can I remove 'duplicates' by taking the row with the higher `load_number`.

I was thinking of some sort of descending `rank()` on the `load_number`,
Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
with max_load_numbers_by_id AS (
  SELECT et.id, MAX(et.load_number) AS max_load_number
  FROM enterprise_table et
  GROUP BY et.id 
)

SELECT et.*
FROM enterprise_table et
JOIN max_load_numbers_by_id mlnbi
  ON et.id = mlnbi.id
  AND et.max_load_number = mlnbi.load_number
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (time, slot_time, region, network) t.*
from mytable t
order by time, slot_time, region, network, load_number desc
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9347bf37c1a48c115a419ceac087ce4e)**:

```
load_number |        id | time     | slot_time | region | network
----------: | --------: | :------- | :-------- | :----- | :------
       1692 | 641131146 | 00:20:00 | 00:20:00  | FX-4   | SBOB   
       1692 | 641131146 | 00:20:00 | 00:20:30  | FX-4   | SBOB   
       1692 | 641131147 | 00:55:00 | 00:55:00  | FX-4   | SBOB   
       1692 | 641131147 | 00:55:00 | 00:55:30  | FX-4   | SBOB
```

Comment: I'm using Teradata. Is there anyway to specify the distinct on?

Answer (score 1):

You can use window function `rank` or `dense_rank` to select most recent load_number. Here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fCr3Yz55eJuyKw1z91dagB/1).

```
select
  load_number, 
  id, 
  time, 
  slot_time, 
  region, 
  network
from
(
  select
    *,
    dense_rank() over(order by load_number desc) as rn
  from myTable
) subq
where rn = 1;
```

output:

```
| load_number | id        | time     | slot_time | region | network |
| ----------- | --------- | -------- | --------- | ------ | ------- |
| 1692        | 641131146 | 00:20:00 | 00:20:00  | FX-4   | SBOB    |
| 1692        | 641131146 | 00:20:00 | 00:20:30  | FX-4   | SBOB    |
| 1692        | 641131147 | 00:55:00 | 00:55:00  | FX-4   | SBOB    |
| 1692        | 641131147 | 00:55:00 | 00:55:30  | FX-4   | SBOB    |
```